# Sharing data between 2 Java EE applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, sharing

We have an application that scans directories to retrieve data and picture on one side and that serves iphone applications through webservices with this data on the other side.

We encounter problems like `JDBCException` of `RollbackException` when we try to access through webservices data while the scans and retrieving of more data occurs. We use java persistence in his hibernate implementation.

Because of that we think dividing our application into two web modules, one for scanning directories and retrieving datas and picture, one for serving datas through webservices.

The problem is how to share the data between the two web modules? it seems that data entered in the scanning module is not immediately available to the webservice module. Is it something to do with the configuration of java persistence?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is how to share the data between the two web modules

You might do the following.

- Put the data into database, which both modules share.
- Send messages between the modules, using the JMS and some message-oriented-middleware.

> Is it something to do with the configuration of java persistence

Are you sure the transactions are being committed?

Comment: In fact the transactions are commited but we haven't tested yet the solution. We expect the data is not replicated between the two web modules because when we insert data into database through phpmyadmin, we need to restart the server so we see the changes in jpa. does just commiting the transactions is enough to get the data being seen from both web modules? Thanks for the help btw, using jms seems to complicated, we prefer a database solution